# Incorrect SQL Statement (debug)

Tags: php, mysql, debugging

My controller.php is including the connection to the database, and I'm accessing information from my database with the following code:

```
function getWidgets(){  
    $widgetQ = "SELECT * FROM tblfinal WHERE Type = 'Widget'";
    global $myPdo;
    $myCommand = $myPdo->prepare($widgetQ);
    $myCommand->execute();
    return $myCommand;
}
```

However, it doesn't seem to like my SQL statement, and gives me the following error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on null on line 11
```

I think this means that my SQL statement isn't actually pulling anything from my database.

Any tips?

Comment: $myPdo does not contain your database connection, you probably aren't connecting before you call the function.

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified, my controller.php is including the connection to the database.

Comment: No, the error is that $myPdo does not contain your database connection, if it did, this would work.

Comment: Your error message says that `$myPdo` is not the object you think it is.  It is actually null.  You can print_r or var dump it to see.